# Blazor component needs to modify value of parent component

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have these two components in my Blazor app:

Component1.razor:

```
<CascadingValue Value=this>
    <Component2/>
</CascadingValue>

<p>@DisplayedText</p>

@code {
    public string DisplayedText = string.Empty;
}
```

Component2.razor:

```
<button @onclick=@(e => { C1.DisplayedText = "testing"; })>Set DisplayedText</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Component1 C1 { get; set; }
}
```

When I click the "Set DisplayedText" button, the text in the `p` element in `Component1` should change to `testing`, but it does not. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Merlin04, this is an abuse and misuse of the cascading value feature. Ordinarily, a parent component communicates with its child via component parameters.

> You can't update a cascaded value from a descendant.

Wrong...

The following code snippet demonstrate a better solution, based on what you do, though it is not optimal because your code and mine as well update a property from a method, when in matter of fact, we should changed the property's value directly, and not through a mediator code (that is a method)

### Component2.razor

```
<button @onclick="@(() => SetDisplayedText.InvokeAsync("testing"))">Set 
                                                 DisplayedText</button>

@code {
   [Parameter]
   public EventCallback<string> SetDisplayedText { get; set; }
}
```

### Component1.razor

```
<Component2 SetDisplayedText="@SetDisplayedText"/>

<p>@DisplayedText</p>

@code {
    private string DisplayedText = string.Empty;

    public void SetDisplayedText(string newText)
   {
       DisplayedText = newText;
   }
}
```

Note that calling the StateHasChanged method is not necessary, as this is the bonus you get when using the EventCallback 'delegate'

Hope this helps...

Comment: That makes sense, would that still be the best way to do it if I had a Component3 that is a child of Component2, and I needed to update DisplayedText from Component3?

Comment: No, using event handlers is suitable only in parent-child relations. In this case, you need a mediator between component1 to component3. A viable solution is to create a service that should be injected into component1 and component3. This service should define a public string property to store the text passed to it  from component3. It should also define event delegate that should be raised when the property is changed (passed value from component3), and subscribers to this event, such as component1, will be notified of this fact (a new value has arrived),

Comment: and access this value, either by reading the value from the property defined in the service or by passing the value in the form of event args. This can be a good exercise for you. Try it. I'm here if you need helps...

Comment: Would the service be created like a normal class? How would I add the delegate?

Answer (score 9):

Merlin04, the following code snippet demonstrate how you can do it. Note that this is really a very simple sample, but it shows how you should code when communication between distant components is required.

Here's the code, copy and run it, and if you have more questions don't hesitate to ask.

### MessageService.cs

```
 public class MessageService
{
    private string message;
    public string Message
    {
        get => message;
        set
        {
            if (message != value)
            {
                message = value;
                if (Notify != null)
                {
                     Notify?.Invoke();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public event Action Notify;
}
```

Note: The service is a normal class... It provides services to other objects, and it should be added to the DI container in Startup.ConfigureServices method to make it available to requesting clients. Add this: to the ConfigureServices method:

```
 services.AddScoped<MessageService>();
```

Note: As you can see I define an event delegate of the Action type, which is invoked from the property's set accessor, when the user type text into a text box in Component3. Triggering this delegate causes the text entered by Components3 to be displayed in the Index component which is the parent of Component2 (see code below).

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@inject MessageService MessageService
@implements IDisposable

<p>I'm the parent of Component2. I've got a message from my grand child: 
                                            @MessageService.Message</p>

<Component2 />

@code {
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    MessageService.Notify += OnNotify;
}

public void OnNotify()
{
    InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });
 }

 public void Dispose()
 {
    MessageService.Notify -= OnNotify;
 }
}
```

Note that we directly bind to the MessageService.Message property, but the StateHasChanged method must be called to refresh the display of the text.

### Component2.razor

```
<h3>Component2: I'm the parent of component three</h3>
<Component3/>

@code {

}
```

### Component3.razor

```
@inject MessageService MessageService

<p>This is component3. Please type a message to my grand parent</p>
<input placeholder="Type a message to grandpa..." type="text" 
@bind="@MessageService.Message" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

Note that in Component3 we bind the MessageService.Message to a text box, and the binding occurs each time you press a key board( input event versus change 
 event).

That is all, hope this helps, and don't hesitate to ask any question.

Comment: +1 - declaring ```public event Action Notify``` - for some reason I never connected that and kept declaring the delegate and then the event based on the delegate. Any cons to your approach? I know the declared delegate approach constrains method signatures, can your ```Action``` version do the same? Upvoted your answer btw, this is how I would have approached this as well.

Comment: The truth is that I do it automatically, without giving it any thought. If I understand you correct, you mean that you usually do something like this:  public delegate void MyAction();
        public event MyAction Notify; This is legitimate and should work... What you do here is defining a custom delegate for a method that has no parameters and does not return a value. This is exactly how the Action defined... constrains are the result of how you define your delegate.

Comment: By defining  public delegate void MyAction<in T>(T obj), you constrain your delegate to encapsulate a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value. This is exactly the pre-defined delegate Action<T>

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for clarifying. Time to brush up on Action and Func again and save myself some typing.

Comment: @enet thanks so much for the help, I was able to get that to work. One question though, why does `StateHasChanged` need to be inside `InvokeAsync`?

Comment: @Merlin04, I can't do that better than the Blazor team, so here's a link where the issue is explained. And don't hesitate to ask me any questions about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state

Comment: Thanks to @enet for this sample, I was trying to find ways for descendant calling ancestor in blazor. This is the microsoft link I found after reading your sample: "In-memory state container service" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service-wasm and this one for third party library https://jonhilton.net/blazor-state-management/

Answer (score 0):

## See enet's answer instead of this

You can't update a cascaded value from a descendant.

Instead, make a method in the parent (Component1) to set the value:

```cs
public void SetDisplayedText(string newText) {
    DisplayedText = newText;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Then, you can call that in the descendant:

```
<button @onclick=@(e => { C1.SetDisplayedText("testing"); })>Set DisplayedText</button>
```